# How to set bottom safe area to XIB in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I want to open custom popup view(designed in XIB) which is displaying from bottom but rightnow in iPhoneX simulator, it displayed from bottom of the screen. i want to open popup in safe area.

**Result in iPhone-X**

[image]

**And XIB Layout with constraints.**

[image]

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46177394/5638630

Comment: Show your code for popup or share storyboard/XIB layout (if you've designed from storyboard/XIB)

Comment: @Krunal, I updated image in my question please  check it

Comment: Share me code, how do you add XIB in you existing view.

Comment: You may have a problem with method - How you add your XIB in your existing view. Share it here. (Use Auto Layout constraint after adding your XIB into your view)

Answer (score 12):

Solution in simple words: **Remove bottom constraint with superview and attach it (bottom constraint) with bottom (anchor) layout constraint of 'Safe Area'**

Follow these steps to find solution:

1. Enable 'Safe Area Layout', if not enabled.
2. Remove 'Bottom constraint' if it shows you connection with with Super view and re-attach with safe layout bottom anchor.  **OR** Double click on bottom constraint and edit from super view to SafeArea bottom anchor

Look at this snapshot:

[image]

Here is result:

[image]

**Update:**

Here is same result with XIB also. I don't see any problem with XIB here.

[image]

Comment: I already tried it but it didn't provide me safe area option when i set bottom constraint

Comment: Hello @krunal, It works well in storyboard's view controller but problem is when we add XIB. In XIB, we cant set bottom to the safe area. that's my original problem.

Comment: I'm getting same result with XIB also. Look at an update.